# Trying to match text content of spinner and text fields but 'withText' and 'withSpinnerText' are returning data about the components instead

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I'm following the Pluralsight tutorial "Android Apps with Kotlin: Tools and Testing" and ran into the following issue:

During Instrumented Tests we check the text in a spinner and two text fields, in the video it just works out but I am running into issues. Here is my test code:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.*
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
import org.junit.Rule
import android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withSpinnerText
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NextThroughNotesTest {
    @Rule @JvmField
    val noteListActivity = ActivityTestRule(NoteListActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun nextThroughNotes() {
        onData(allOf(instanceOf(NoteInfo::class.java), equalTo(DataManager.notes[0]))).perform(click())

        for (index in 0..DataManager.notes.lastIndex) {
            val note = DataManager.notes[index]

            onView(withId(R.id.spinnerCourses)).check(
                matches(withSpinnerText(note.course?.title)))
            onView(withId(R.id.textNoteTitle)).check(
                matches(withText(note.title)))
            onView(withId(R.id.textNoteText)).check(
                matches(withText(note.text)))

            if (index != DataManager.notes.lastIndex) {
                onView(allOf(withId(R.id.action_next), isEnabled())).perform()
            }
        }

        onView(withId(R.id.action_next)).check(matches(isEnabled()))
    }
}
```

Taking a look at the error message I get the following:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "Android Programming with Intents"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "Android Programming with Intents"
Got: "AppCompatSpinner{id=2131230878, res-name=spinnerCourses, visibility=VISIBLE, width=912, height=63, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@1f42cb1, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=84.0, y=42.0, child-count=1}"
```

The error messages are similar if I comment out the line about the spinner. I have tried to add 'containsString' as per a previous StackOverflow solution I found but obviously that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To remedy this issue, you want to be sure to have androidTestImplementation dependency entries for the following libraries:

```
androidx.test:core
androidx.test:rules
androidx.test.ext:junit
androidx.test:runner
androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core
```

For reference, the following is the dependency section from a project I recently created that relies on AndroidX rather than the Android Support Libraries:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

credits to [Jim Wilson, the author of the same course on Pluralsight](https://jwhh.com/2019/06/10/androidx-automated-ui-test-dependencies/).